Telegram API получение статистики о канале
Всем привет, может кто знает как лучше сделать, что использовать?
Задача такова: добавляться бот (именно бот) в какой-либо телеграм канал. Необходимо получить инфу о канале (посты, просмотры и т.п). Насколько я знаю bot api не поддерживает получение такой информации. Так как можно это реализовать, чтобы работало даже в приватных канал (в которых естественно добавлен наш бот).
К примеру, как в сервисе tgstat работает, только мне нужно насколько развернутая инфа, чисто базовая информацию необходима.
Уже создан bot в BotFathere, он нужен для отправки постов в телеграм каналы в которые он добавлен, бот работает на aiogram. А получение информации о постах на aiogram невозможно сделать.
